# Converting JSON object to a csv file

Tags: java, scala

```
[{"sensor":"T","value":31.0},{"sensor":"P","value":1.0},{"sensor":"A","value":421.0},{"sensor":"H","value":62.0},{"sensor":"R","value":0.43390116},{"sensor":"S","value":43.0}]
```

I want to convert this to a csv file like

```
T     P    A    H      R   S
31.0 1.0 421.0 62.0 .4339 43.0
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

For this use gson.jar to convert json into array of bean objects. Then iterate through the array of objects and write there values to any stream or file in CSV (Comma Separated Values) format.